# Error: expected identifier before '#' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, token, identifier

After searching for this compile-time error, I found a lot of closed ones, but usually with ')' or '}' which didn't seem to be the problem I'm facing.

I'm developing an iPhone app and have a `UITableView` within a `UINavigationViewController`. I'd like to select a table cell and push a new view onto the navigation stack. I'm able to push a generic `UIViewController` onto the stack, but when I use this `DetailViewController` (created via File->New File...->UIViewController subclass w/ XIB file, I get this error: "error: expected identifier before '#' token"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: does it say which line or even which file the error is coming from?

Comment: This is usually caused by blue token bubbles which you should replace with actual values, names, etc. Try tabbing or pressing `Ctrl-.` to cycle through them.

Comment: Thanks for your help @aopsfan and @Costique! I believe the error had to do with my first line where I defined DetailViewController and don't think it was because I left blue bubbles there. I ended up changing the method to use this instead:

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]detailViewController.title = @"DetailView";
 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 
 [detailViewController release];

Answer (score 1):

Do a search through your project for the `#` character it's usually a missing terminator or syntax error before that.

Comment: Thanks @Abizem. Because I created a ViewController file w/ NIB, I think I didn't need to use the initWithNibName: call... instead just created a new DetailViewController (see above). This seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the top of your .h and .m files, you've most probably mistakenly inputted a character there. It will look like `s#import "..."` or something like that

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. Because I created a ViewController file w/ NIB, I think I didn't need to use the initWithNibName: call... instead just created a new DetailViewController (see above). This seemed to work for me.